# Question about using quote and coref for Chinese

Tags: stanford-nlp, quote

I'm trying to extract quotes and coref information from Chinese data using StanfordCoreNLP 4.2.0, in addition to the rest of the pipeline. I have been able to get tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp to work using this code:

"java -cp "+ class_path +"*; -Xmx" + memory + "g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -threads "+ nthreads + " -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp" + " -filelist " + file_list + " -outputDirectory "+ output_folder + " -outputFormat xml"

but when I add coref and/or quote to the annotators, it doesn't output any files (my current output is xml, but I also tried text). I've tried:

- tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp,quote,coref
- tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp,quote
- tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp,coref -coref.algorithm neural
- tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,kbp,coref

And I've tried each with parse instead of depparse. I couldn't get the parse annotator to work even with just tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse - it doesn't output anything.

Any advice on why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated!